# transforming jquery to java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform

I have this script made with jQuery which I am using to show / hide divs on my page. 
I really need it to be made purely in JavaScript and I have no idea how to do this.
Could anyone help me ??? 
I think I need a converter or something . . .

```
$("#optiuni").children().click(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).attr('name')).show().siblings().hide();
    /*Gives the  link-activ class to the link that i clicked an link-inactive to all others*/
    $(this).attr('class','link-activ').siblings().attr('class','link-neactiv');
});
/*this makes shure that the first option from my list is active  incarcarea paginii*/
$("#optiuni li.prima").children().click();
```

Sample markup:

```
<div id="lista">
  <ul id="optiuni">
    <li id="titlu-lista-p"> <p class="listname-t">Past Events </p></li>

    <li name="opt-1" class="prima"><a href="#"><p class="listdata">28.02.2011</p><p class="listname">TABU Oscar Party</p> </a></li>

    <li name="opt-2" ><a href="#"><p class="listdata">24.03.2011</p><p class="listname">Cheese & Wine</p></a></li>
    <li name="opt-8"><a href="#"><p class="listdata">08.04.2011</p><p class="listname">George Baicea</p></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="centru">
  <div id="continut" >
    <div id="opt-2" class="galerie" style="background-color: black;">
      <iframe id="gal" src="cheese/index.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="opt-1" class="galerie" style="background-color: black;">
      <iframe  src="tabu/index.html"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="opt-8" class="galerie" style="background-color: blue;">
      <iframe   src="no-ev/index.html"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you need Java or Javascript? these are two distinct things =)

Comment: jquery IS javascript, so what's the problem?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery? It saves you tons of work...

Comment: Can you at least show some effort and try for yourself. Happy to correct mistakes but we are not a free coding service! You will learn nothing copying and pasting a solution.

Comment: Well you have to think about what the functions are doing and think about a corresponding solution with "pure" JavaScript. E.g. `element.style.display = 'none'` for `hide()`. Or have a look at the jQuery source of those functions.

Comment: i must use javascript code that has nothing to do with the jquery library . . . i know it saves ton of work but there's nothing i can do about this

Comment: @Mihai B: why do you want to convert from jQuery to javascript? jQuery works across all browser,if you convert to plain javascript , it will not work in other browsers. also there are lot of hacks written in jQuery for browser bugs, which is time consuming to replicate in javascript and even for testing.

Comment: @redsquare: i know this is not a free codeing service i just asked for help because i don't have any time to start learning to code in java script in 2 hours and be shure it is functional

Comment: @suresh : i can't use jQuery + i just need this pice of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do this based on the [markup you linked to](http://www.avantsolutions.ro/exp.txt) in your comment, as there are some assumptions you could make based on the jQuery version which don't hold when you see the markup.

[jsFiddle with a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/insin/WYn55/3/).

```
// IE sucks
function addEvent(el, name, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(name, handler, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    // Make sure "this" references the element we're adding the event handler to
    el.attachEvent('on' + name, function() { handler.call(el, window.event); });
  }
}

function eachElementSibling(el, func) {
  var childNodes = el.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, sibling; sibling = childNodes[i]; i++) {
    if (sibling.nodeType !== 1 || sibling === el) {
      continue;
    }
    func(sibling);
  }
}

function activateLink() {
  var elToShow = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('name'));
  elToShow.style.display = '';
  eachElementSibling(elToShow, function(s) { s.style.display = 'none'; });
  this.className = 'link-active';
  eachElementSibling(this, function(s) {
    if (s.getAttribute('name')) { s.className = 'link-neactiv'; }
  });
}

var items = document.getElementById('optiuni').getElementsByTagName('li');
var initialItem = null;
for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
  // Need to filter, as non-link items are also present in the list
  if (item.getAttribute('name')) {
    addEvent(item, 'click', activateLink);
    if (item.className === 'prima') {
      initialItem= item;
    }
  }
}
if (initialItem) {
  activateLink.call(initialItem)
}
```

Comment: Very nice response, I haven't tested but this should get the OP there.  And to those who ask "why no jQuery" think of the reasons it's better to load this rather than a 75k library 100k page views a day, or any number of other similar situations.

Comment: tank you very much i will try it right now and if i have any problems i will contact you back

Comment: i tested it and it dosen't really do anything can't figure out why i will attrach bellow the entire page source

Comment: I know it can be necessary to exclude as many files as possible, but it sounds like homework...